# How can I test custom ValidationAttribute classes in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, custom-attributes

I have a custom validator attribute which I am trying to unit test.  In my unit test I am doing the following.

```
var testModel = new TestModel();
var testContext = new ValidationContext(testModel, null, null);
var attribute = new MyCustomAttribute();

attribute.Validate(testModel, testContext);
```

When calling `attribute.Validate` it correctly calls my `IsValid` method but `attribute.Validate` is `void` so obviously doesn't return anything.  Any ideas on how I can get a hook into the `ValidationResult` would be greatly appreciated.

---

After doing some reading on the `ValidationAttribute.Validate` Method it looks like if it fails validation it will throw a `ValidationException`, so this kind of answers my question.

Comment: Thinking out loud here. If your validation suceeds, then you shouldn't have any validation errors in error dictionary - so checking whether it's empty is one test. Then I would test for specific errors in the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can invoke the validation the same way MVC does using the ModelValidator.  Something like this (your mileage here may vary, can't remember all the calls off the top of my head, will try to replace with working code later):

```
var modelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, model.GetType());

var validator = ModelValidator.GetModelValidator(modelMetadata, base.ControllerContext);

var result = validator.Validate(instance)
```